# Latest font name is not getting after change font in Word 2016

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I added One button in the ribbon which returns the current Font name. I type some text in MS Word 2016 and then Change the entire font name. After changing the font name, I want to get the font name using C#. I am using VSTO.

The following code is inside the button Click event.

```
  var currentApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
  string fontName = currentApp.ActiveDocument.Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont].Font.Name;
```

but I am always getting the same font that is before the change.

Comment: You are getting the font of a built in word style. Not the font of current document / range.

Comment: Actually, My default font is Calibri and I changed to Segoe UI Emoji by selecting all text and now I click my custom button to get font name, it is not returning me Segoe UI Emoji. It still returns Calibri.

Comment: As Ryan has explained, your code is getting the font used in the _style_. Selecting text and applying a new font is local formatting, it doesn't change the font set in the style. You want to get the font of your selection, not the style.

Comment: There is not selected text available.

Comment: It gives me changes text using App.ActiveDocument.Range().Font class